# Error in Android Manifest - the markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android

Hello I am a beginner programmer using eclipse for app development and received this error in my manifest when trying to run a simple program.  I have taken other suggestions based on other responses to people with the same error but so far nothing seems to have worked.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
{

```
<<<<<<< Original
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.JTInc.tag"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.JTInc.tag.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.JTInc.tag.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.JTInc.tag.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.JTInc.tag.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
        android:parentActivityName="com.JTInc.tag.LoginActivity">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.JTInc.tag.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCZ6x93L7BBTILLTdWkDT8Da6a8f4mVo1o" />

</application>
```

Comment: Is the "<<<<<<< Original" line part of your file? If it is, that is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the closing `</manifest>` at the end of your manifest.

Also the beginning `<<<<<<< Original` text should not be there.

Comment: The closing manifest is there it just didn't get copied, sorry.  I thought I had tried deleting the Original thing earlier, but I guess not because it works now.  Thanks.